# Maybe [hdpi] is not high enough, add [hidpi] as a synonym?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I have seen posts tagged with [hidpi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/hidpi) twice or thrice in the past, and each time I replaced it with [hdpi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/hdpi), whose tag info reads:

> High DPI (dots per inch) screen resolutions, e.g. 4k/UHD/QHD screens
>   in a relatively small form factor, e.g. laptops/tablets. Use this tag
>   for issues relating to the Ubuntu experience on HDPI screens.

Largely because of Apple, the term "HiDPI" is also becoming popular (maybe more popular - at any rate, it is easier to read than "HDPI" for me).

I think [hidpi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/hidpi) should be added as a synonym, or made the master and [hdpi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/hdpi) the synonym.

Answer (score 9):

I vote that we make [hdpi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/hdpi) a synonym of [hidpi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/hidpi), as the latter is easier to read and seems to be the "official" name, at least according to the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI) and regular Google search results. Note the [related queries](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?q=hidpi,hdpi) on Google Trends. From that data itself, we can easily say that "HDPI" refers to mobile displays while "HiDPI" is used for computers. As we aren't [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/), it would only make sense to use [hidpi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/hidpi) as the master tag.

I would, however, express caution turning 4k, UHD, and QHD into synonyms of [hidpi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/hidpi), as 4k screens are not always HiDPI. Synonymizing [retina](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/retina) (or whatever the tag is) would be a good idea, but this tag doesn't seem to exist yet, making synonymizing it relatively useless.

Answer (score 4):

I would tend to agree due to the recent popularity of the hidpi acronym. I don't think it matters too much which is master and which is synonym, but I would agree having both and having one a synonym of the other would make sense if we are to have either of them.

I can't think of a compelling reason to have either tag to be honest, as I don't see what the screen technology has to do with the OS or why anyone would follow either tag. Perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: hidpi seems to me more intuitive

Comment: 4K refers to the number of pixel, not to pixel density. It is not a synonym. :)

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto Point taken, post corrected.